# How to create ARRAY?

Tags: php, json

I want to Create an ARRAY (array name:"queue") for this ArrayList using PHP... I have the php codes and the output below:

```
[
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 17:32:32","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"7","info1":"2","info2":"91","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 17:31:01","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"10","info1":"2","info2":"1466069459.6496","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 16:28:41","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"8","info1":"2","info2":"113","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 16:26:48","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"10","info1":"2","info2":"1466065606.6445","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:47:25","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"7","info1":"4","info2":"454","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:39:51","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"10","info1":"4","info2":"1466062787.6382","info3":"3"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:27:45","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"8","info1":"5","info2":"339","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:22:06","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"10","info1":"5","info2":"1466061721.6337","info3":"4"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:18:16","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"7","info1":"2","info2":"50","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:17:26","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"10","info1":"2","info2":"1466061444.6325","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:14:06","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"7","info1":"5","info2":"60","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 15:13:06","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"10","info1":"5","info2":"1466061181.6318","info3":"4"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:52:52","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"7","info1":"3","info2":"50","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:52:02","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"10","info1":"3","info2":"1466059919.6275","info3":"3"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:49:50","qname":"5","qagent":"28","qevent":"1","info1":"1","info2":"1","info3":"2"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:25:44","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"7","info1":"47","info2":"162","info3":"1"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:23:02","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"10","info1":"47","info2":"1466058176.6227","info3":"5"},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:22:51","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"0","info1":"15000","info2":"","info3":""},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:22:35","qname":"5","qagent":"50","qevent":"0","info1":"0","info2":"","info3":""},
   {"datetime":"2016-06-16 14:22:30","qname":"5","qagent":"53","qevent":"0","info1":"15000","info2":"","info3":""}
]
```

This is My PHP codes:

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"qstatslite")or die("error");

$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM queue_stats ORDER BY queue_stats_id DESC LIMIT 20");


$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
//$return_arr['queue_stats_id'] = $row['queue_stats_id'];
$row_array['datetime'] = $row['datetime'];
$row_array['qname'] = $row['qname'];
$row_array['qagent'] = $row['qagent'];
$row_array['qevent'] = $row['qevent'];
$row_array['info1'] = $row['info1'];
$row_array['info2'] = $row['info2'];
$row_array['info3'] = $row['info3'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$output = json_encode(array('return_arr' => $return_arr));
echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

I want the output to have a title "queue" before the Lists.. Your help will be appreciated. ty

Comment: When I answered, your question was a lot less detailed. Do you want to translate JSON to php, or php to JSON?

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to put my PHP codes.. i already added it above.

Comment: That's fine, but did you want to translate JSON to PHP, or PHP to JSON? I'm not sure I understand what you want exactly.

Comment: I want to translate php to json..

Comment: OH, you want `queue` to be an extra field within every row? Or do you just want the array to be named `queue`?

Comment: Yes I want the array to be named queue.. can you help me with that? hehe sorry im new to json.

Comment: please see my updated answer :)

Comment: Wow! genius! Thanks a lot dude! i will accept your answer for that.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a `JSON` array.
Of you want to translate it to an array in PHP, there is a special function for this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

usage:

```
$queue = json_decode($json);
```

once done, you can use PHP's `list()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

usage:

```
$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";
```

-- if you want to translate JSON to PHP, you can use `json_encode();`, which you seem to already know. However, you are using `json_encode()` twice, which could cause problems.

```
$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
//$return_arr['queue_stats_id'] = $row['queue_stats_id'];
$row_array['datetime'] = $row['datetime'];
$row_array['qname'] = $row['qname'];
$row_array['qagent'] = $row['qagent'];
$row_array['qevent'] = $row['qevent'];
$row_array['info1'] = $row['info1'];
$row_array['info2'] = $row['info2'];
$row_array['info3'] = $row['info3'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$output = json_encode(array('queue' => $return_arr));
echo $output;
```

Now, if you were to send this JSON back to `javascript` or whatever, it would look like this:

```
//get values
jsonData.queue.datetime;
jsonData.queue.qagent;
```

if you were to simply decode it back to a php array again, it would look like this:

```
<?php
  $queue = json_decode($output)['queue'];
?>
```